# When to define methods on interface and when not to?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using a Objective-C framework for game development called Cocos2d-iphone.

This is how I create a button-graphic in the game:

```
CCMenuItemImage *battle;
    battle = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"BattleFightOption1.png" selectedImage:@"BattleFightOption2.png"
                                           target:self selector:@selector(battleFightOption)];
```

Basically, when the user clicks the button, method `battleFightOption` runs.

But I wonder, I never did define `battleFightOption` in the interface.. so, my question is: when is it necessary to define a method in the interface, and when is it not?

Answer (score 1):

In short, every method that is meant to be used from outside the class must be declared in the interface; methods that are internal to the class implementation are omitted. The latter are typically declared in a class extension.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a selector like `@selector(methodName:)`, `methodName:` is called dynamically at runtime. The compiler doesn't have to know where it is, and doesn't check that the method exists when you compile.

However, it is still a good idea to declare it privately, which is generally done by putting an unnamed category at the top of the `.m` file (generally referred to as a *class extension*):

```
#import "Class.h"

@interface Class ()

- (void)privateMethod;

@end

@implementation Class
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything that you intend to be public, called outside of the class, should be defined in the interface. If you are going to only use `@selector(battleFightOption)` you really do not need to define the method anywhere but I would recommend that you add a definition in the [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html) just as you would any other private method.